# testing multiple variables on picaxe

Tags: variables, picaxe

I am trying to make a yahtzee scorer on picaxe, it is all okay other that the fact that there are so many different combinations. I am wandering if there is a way of testing whether 4 of my 5 variables are the same(no more and no less) without having to go through all the different combinations eg:
if b1=b2 and b1=b3 and b1=b4 and b1!=b5 then ...
if b1=b2 and b1=b3 and b1=b5 and b1!=b4 then ...

In summary is there a way athat i can see if only 4 out of the 5 variables are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've told us this is for a Yahtzee scorer, I assume that the five variables we need to compare represent the throw of five dice, and so their values will only be between 1 and 6.

In that case a functional solution is to count how many of the variables are equal to a test value, and repeat this for test values between 1 and 6:

```
; define symbols for the two variables we will use
symbol same_test = b6
symbol same_count = b7

b1 = 3: b2 = 3: b3 = 3: b4 = 3: b5 = 1 ; test data
gosub test4same
if same_count = 4 then found_4_same ; do something
; else program flow continues here
end

found_4_same:
sertxd("found 4 the same")
end

test4same: ; test if any four of the variables are equal
same_count = 0
for same_test = 1 to 6
    if b1 = same_test then gosub found_one
    if b2 = same_test then gosub found_one
    if b3 = same_test then gosub found_one
    if b4 = same_test then gosub found_one
    if b5 = same_test then gosub found_one
    if same_count = 4 then exit ; 4 variables were equal to same_test
    same_count = 0
next
return

found_one:
inc same_count
return
```

`gosub test4same` will check whether four out of the five variables `b1` to `b5` are equal to the same number, for numbers between 1 and 6. If they are, the variable `same_count` will be 4 and the number the four variables are equal to will be in `same_test`.

Using the `if ... then exit` structure before resetting `same_count` back to zero was the most efficient way I could think of to tell whether we found four the same or not.

The code after the two `symbol` statements and before the label `test4same` is just to demonstrate that it works; replace this with your actual program.

In principle you could use the same technique over any range of values, but obviously it would get a bit slow if you needed to test all 256 possible values of a byte variable.